# How to find object in python list by attribute

Tags: python-3.x, flask

If I have a list created like this:

```
list = [
    {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "something 1"
    },
    {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "something 2"
    }
]
```

and I want to grab information from one of the list items, using the id from the url like this:

```
@route.app('item/<int:id>')
def item(id):
  name = ???
  return render_template('index.html', name=name)
```

how would I get the name of the object in the list with the specific id from the url?

Comment: What have you tried, and what exactly is the problem with it?

Comment: a for loop of the list items, but I can't seam to get it to set a variable for name that I can pass to my template.

Comment: So give a [mcve] of that.

Comment: I am a beginner and I don't have any more information to offer. I have voted to delete my question. thank you for letting me know that it is not up to the standards for this site. I will try to make things more complicated and less straight forward in the future.

Comment: It's *your question*, you can unilaterally delete it if you don't want to post your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple for loop will do your work:

```
@route.app('item/<int:id>')
def item(id):
   some_list = [
    {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "something 1"
    },
    {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "something 2"
    }
   ] 
  name = ""
  for obj in some_list:
    if obj['id'] == id:
          name = obj['name']
  return render_template('index.html', name=name)
```

Comment: There is an indention error in your if statement, but thank you for the straight forward answer to my straight forward question. It worked, you're my hero.

Comment: All the best :)